# WebUSB `USBDevice.configurations` differs across platforms

Tags: javascript, android, webusb

I'm setting up a connection between a webpage and a thermal printer over WebUSB.
On my laptop (Mac, Chrome 91), the result is as expected: a device shows up, I can open it and select some configuration.
When trying to connect my phone (Android, Chrome 91) to the thermal printer however, the WebUSB object has no configurations available for me to select, and thus I cannot use the printer there.

How could it be that the same `USBDevice` has different configurations on MacOS and Android?

Code to reproduce:

```js
const device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{}] });
console.log(device.configurations);
```

This logs `[USBConfiguration]` on MacOS and `[]` on Android (when selecting thermal printer CITIZEN CT-E651).

I have searched throughout the issues of the WebUSB specification, but couldn't find an answer to this question not a solution there.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in Chrome. Please file an issue report in [the project issue tracker](https://crbug.com/new). To help collect more information please include any log output that is shown in chrome://device-log on the Android device after calling requestDevice().

To compare against the behavior on macOS please, on your macOS device, visit chrome://usb-internals, click the "Devices" tab, find your device and click the "Inspect" button and then click the "Get Configuration Descriptor" button and attach a screenshot of the resulting page to the issue you file.